# Weak Convergence of Localized Functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Asking for some help filling the gaps from a proof from a text.

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be an unbounded domain, not being bounded in any direction (in particular, we don't have Poincare inequality).

Define $\mathbb{V}=\{f\in C^\infty_0(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^n):\nabla\cdot f=0\}$. Let $Y$ be the completion of $\mathbb{V}$ with respect to the norm 
$$||u||=\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2$$
Then $Y$ is a Hilbert space with the obvious inner product. Note that if $\Omega$ were bounded in any direction, then (by Poincare inequality) the norm above would be equivalent to the $H^1$ norm and in particular, $Y$ would be a subset of $H^1_0$. That is not the case here.

Now the actual problem. We are trying to prove that if $u_m$ converges to $u$ weakly in $Y$, then $u_m$ converges strongly in $L^2_{loc}(\Omega)$ (i.e. $u_m$ converges strongly to $u$ in $L^2(\mathbb{O})$ for every bounded subset $\mathbb{O}\subset\Omega$.

The proof proceeds as follows. Let $\psi\in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R})$ such that $\psi=1$ on $\mathbb{O}$, an arbitrary bounded subset of $\Omega$. And, let $\Omega'$ be a bounded subset of $\Omega$ containing the support of $\psi$ (in particular it contains $\mathbb{O}$).

Then, the functions $\psi u_m$ belong to $H^1_0(\Omega')$ (OK, so far so good),

and since $u_m$ converges to $u$ weakly in $Y$ we have that $\psi u_m$ converges to $\psi u$ weakly in $H^1_0(\Omega')$.

This is the part I'm having trouble with. So I think because $\psi$ is nice and all and perhaps the fact that $Y$ is continuously embedded in $L^\alpha(\Omega)$, $\alpha>2$, by the definition of $Y$ and Sobolev embedding, it's possible to conclude that $\psi u_m$ are uniformly bounded in $H^1_0(\Omega')$, following essentially because $u_m$ are uniformly bounded in $Y$ (they weakly converge). And from uniform boundedness, it follows, that, passing to a subsequence if needed, $\psi u_m$ converges weakly to some $w\in H^1_0(\Omega')$. Assuming everything above is correct, all that is left is to show is that $w=\psi u$. It seems obvious. By the logic of "well, what else could it be?", indeed $w$ and $\psi u$ should be equal and we would conclude $\psi u_m$ converges weakly to $\psi u$ in $H^1_0(\Omega')$

So, can someone help me complete the logic in the last step?

(Also, if you're curious, the proof of the original statement in its entirety is finished after one more sentence)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The construction does not work if $\Omega=\mathbb R^n$. So $\Omega$ has some boundary.
Take $R>0$ large enough such that $\Omega' \subset  \overline{ B_R(0)}$ and
$B_R(0) \cap \Omega$ contains some smooth part of the boundary $\partial\Omega$ (This has to be made precise). Then the Poincare inequality is valid on $B_R(0)\cap \Omega$
for all $u\in Y$.

The sequence $(\nabla(\psi u_m))$ is bounded in $L^2$, then by Poincare inequality  the sequence $(\psi u_m)$ is bounded in $H^1_0(\Omega')$.

Let me prove that the weak limits coincide. Let $f\in (H^1_0(\Omega'))^*$. Then $f(\psi u_m)\to f( w)$. The mapping $v\mapsto f(\psi\cdot v)$ is continuous on $Y$:
$$
| f(\psi \cdot v)|\le \|f\|_{(H^1_0(\Omega'))^*} \|\psi\cdot u\|_{H^1(\Omega')}
\le  \|f\|_{(H^1_0(\Omega'))^*} \|\psi\|_{W^{1,\infty}} \|u\|_{H^1(\Omega')}\\
\le \|f\|_{(H^1_0(\Omega'))^*} \|\psi\|_{W^{1,\infty}} \|u\|_{H^1(B_R)}\\
\le \|f\|_{(H^1_0(\Omega'))^*} \|\psi\|_{W^{1,\infty}} c_{B_R} \|\nabla u\|_{L^2(B_R)}\\
\le \|f\|_{(H^1_0(\Omega'))^*} \|\psi\|_{W^{1,\infty}} c_{B_R} \|u\|_Y.
$$
This implies $f(\psi u_m)\to f(\psi u)$. Hence $\psi u=w$.

Comment: Could you explain how you can conclude that "the Poincare inequality is valid on $B_R(0)$ for all $u\in Y$?

Comment: On $B_R(0)\cap \Omega$. The idea is to mak e$B_R(0)$ large enough that it contains a significant part of the boundary of $\Omega$. On that boundary,  $u$ is zero. And Poincare holds on $\Omega\cap B_R$.

Comment: Hmmm...but this space $Y$. Because it's not a completion under the $H^1(\Omega)$ norm, can we still say that all elements of $Y$ vanish on the boundary of $\Omega$ in the trace sense? In fact, $Y$ isn't even contained in $H^1$, so I dont think we can necessarily talk about the boundary values of elements of $Y$.